# How to format the left legend on chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart and I want to format the values on the left side to money format. The image is where I want to change.
[the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZII6.png)

That's my code so far:

```
  this.Chart = new Chart('kpi', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: cat,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: Value,
        label: "Categorias",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(26, 179, 148, 0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(26, 179, 148, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    events: ['mousemove', 'click'],
    },
    hover: {
      mode: "nearest",
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'data',
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
      }
      }]
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Categorias',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontColor: 'rgba(26, 179, 148, 1)',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "nearest",
      callbacks: {
        title: (item, data) => {
        },
        label: (item, data) => {
          let index = item.index;
          item.value = numeral(data.datasets[0].data[index]).format('$0,0.00');
          return `${data.labels[index]}: ${item.value}`
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I want to format with ".format('$0,0.00')" like on the label, or something like that, but I don't know how to format those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

This is a sample code to format the y axis value from the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html) page of chartjs. You can use this callback to format your labels.